# Combining only few columns to 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-outer-join

I have 2 tables tbl1, tbl2.

Sample data of `tbl1`:

| Id | Name | CreatedOn | SpentAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2023/03/31 | 1000 |
| 2 | Test | 2023/03/31 | 14000 |
| 3 | Mark | 2023/03/31 | 2000 |
| 4,5 | Robert,Gustin | 2023/03/31 | 700 |

Sample data of `tbl2`:

| Id | Name | CreatedOn | UsedAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2023/03/31 | 2000 |
| 7 | Grace | 2023/03/31 | 4000 |
| 2 | Test | 2023/03/31 | 10000 |
| 9,1 | Mary,abc | 2023/03/31 | 1000 |

Expected output:

| Id | Name | SpentAmt | SpentAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2 | Test | 14000 | 10000 |
| 3 | mark | 2000 | null |
| 4,5 | Robert,gustin | 700 | null |
| 7 | grace | null | 4000 |
| 9,1 | Mary,abc | null | 1000 |

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT id, name, spentamt AS amt
FROM tbl1
WHERE createdon >= '2021-04-01'
GROUP BY id, name

SELECT id, name, usedamt AS amt
FROM tbl2
WHERE createdon >= '2021-04-01'
GROUP BY id, name
```

Both individual queries return the expected results, but combining the two isn't working properly

Comment: What did you try? What is working? What is not?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: *"The data in both id and name columns may not be same in both tables and few of the records might have comma separated values as well"*, just edit your question and provide a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4

Comment: Given that your data is not normalized (multi-valued attributes illustrated in last row of tbl1) but you are expecting to parse and recontruct normalized records in your query there are 2 problems to solve here. You also did not state how you attempted to "combine" the queries

Comment: _Individual query gives expected result_ - really no error?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `full join`; I don't think that you need aggregation here.

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, 
    coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name, 
    t1.spentamt, 
    t2.usedamt
from (select * from tbl1 where createdon >= '2021-04-01') t1
full join (select * from tbl2 where createdon >= '2021-04-01') t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Note that I moved the date filtering *within* subqueries, so it happens before the `full join`.

Comment: The data in both id and name columns may not be same in both tables and few of the records might have comma separated values as well

Comment: @Test If you have records with comma separated values, that is a **broken** schema and you should do whatever you can to fix it.

Comment: its not working its only working for the records which i have only in one table not working for the records which are in both the tables that to with many times i am getting records like duplicates Id Name spentamt usedamt
1 abc NULL 
1 abc NULL 
1 abc NULL

Comment: @Test Also: running on this on the provided sample data will give the expected result. If this isn't adequate, you need to **update the question** so the sample data covers that scenario.

Comment: perhaps you just need to use group by? do you have more than one row with same id per table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cte or Full join to solve the problem

```
;with _Listtbl1 as (
                    select id,
                           name,
                           sum( spentamt) as amt
                    FROM tbl1
                    where createdon >= '2021-04-01'
                    group by id,
                           name
),_Listtbl2 as (
            select id,
                   name,
                  sum( usedamt)   as usedamt
            FROM tbl2
            where createdon >= '2021-04-01'
            group by id,
                   name
       )

select ISNULL(a.Id,b.Id) as Id
, ISNULL(a.name,b.name) as name
, a.amt as amt
, b.usedamt as usedamt

from _Listtbl1  a
full join _Listtbl2 b on a.Name=b.Name

order by ISNULL(a.Id,b.Id)
```

Result

| Id | Id | amt | usedamt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2 | Test | 14000 | 10000 |
| 3 | Mark | 2000 | NULL |
| 4,5 | Robert,Gustin | 700 | NULL |
| 7 | Grace | NULL | 4000 |
| 9,1 | Mary,abc | NULL | 1000 |

--

You can create insert base data  with the following statements:

```
drop table if exists tbl1
create table tbl1(Id nvarchar(500), Name nvarchar(500), CreatedOn date, SpentAmt bigint)


insert into tbl1(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  SpentAmt) values ('1'   ,'abc', '2023/03/31'    ,1000)
insert into tbl1(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  SpentAmt) values ('2'   ,'Test',    '2023/03/31'    ,14000)
insert into tbl1(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  SpentAmt) values ('3'   ,'Mark',    '2023/03/31'    ,2000)
insert into tbl1(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  SpentAmt) values ('4,5' ,'Robert,Gustin',   '2023/03/31'    ,700)



drop table if exists tbl2
create table tbl2(Id nvarchar(500), Name nvarchar(500), CreatedOn date, UsedAmt bigint)


insert into tbl2(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  UsedAmt)  values('1'    ,'abc', '2023/03/31'    ,2000)
insert into tbl2(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  UsedAmt)  values('7'    ,'Grace',   '2023/03/31',   4000)
insert into tbl2(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  UsedAmt)  values('2'    ,'Test',    '2023/03/31',   10000)
insert into tbl2(Id ,Name,  CreatedOn,  UsedAmt)  values('9,1', 'Mary,abc'  ,'2023/03/31',  1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `UNION ALL` the tables and then `GROUP BY` the result:

```
select id, Name, sum(SpentAmt), sum(UsedAmt)
from
(
  select id, Name, SpentAmt, null as UsedAmt
  from tbl1 WHERE createdon >= '2023/04/01'
  union all
  select id, Name, null, UsedAmt
  from tbl2 WHERE createdon >= '2023/04/01'
) dt
group by id, Name;
```